# Why onmouseover() function works with attribute onmouseover="javascript code" but doesn't work with addEventListener() function?

Tags: javascript

My point is to trigger the `onmouseover` event in javascript code. I used the function
`onmouseover()` on an element. But it doesn't works in some situations.

This is a demo code:

HTML file:

`<p id="p-id">Text Text</p>`

External Javascript file:

```
var myP = document.getElementById("p-id");
myP.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";     
});
// trigger the mouseover:
myP.onmouseover(); // console error: onmouseover is not a function.
```

But `onmouseover()` function works well when I use the attribute `onmouseover="javascript code"` on the element:

HTML file:

`<p id="p-id" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red'">Text Text</p>`

External Javascript file:

```
var myP = document.getElementById("p-id");
// trigger the mouseover:
myP.onmouseover(); // works well
```

I have been searching the reason for ages but I have no clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onmouseover` property is a *setter/getter* on `HTMLElement.prototype`:

```js
var myP = document.getElementById("p-id");
const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onmouseover');
console.log(descriptor);
console.log(descriptor.get.call(myP));
```

```html
<p id="p-id" onmouseover="console.log('fn')">Text Text</p>
```

When the getter is invoked, it will return either the handler that was previously attached using the *setter*, eg `elm.onmouseover = someFn`, or it will return the inline handler function.

In your upper code, the handler is *neither* inline nor is it attached via invoking the setter, so accessing the `onmouseover` property of the element returns `null`, which can't be called.

In your lower code, the handler is *inline*, so it's returned by accessing the `onmouseover` property, which invokes the getter.

---

It's good practice to *never* use inline handlers [they have too many problems to be worth using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), and to also not attach handlers via `.on` properties (because then, if another script tries to attach a handler to the same element, it'll overwrite the earlier handler).

If you want to trigger a listener function you just attached, you can either save the function in a variable first, then call it:

```js
var myP = document.getElementById("p-id");
const fn = () => myP.style.backgroundColor = "red";     
myP.addEventListener("mouseover", fn);
fn();
```

```html
<p id="p-id">Text Text</p>
```

Or dispatch an event to the element through the DOM:

```js
var myP = document.getElementById("p-id");
myP.addEventListener("mouseover", () => myP.style.backgroundColor = "red");
myP.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'));
```

```html
<p id="p-id">Text Text</p>
```